# Writing a simple text game in java. How to display items picked

Tags: java

I am trying to write the ("That's right, you brought: " + threeItems) part so that it specifies each item, and not just a copy of what the input is into the variable 'threeItems'

```
System.out.println("What items did you bring with again? (pick 3)");
System.out.println("(Crowbar, pistol, knife, key, flask, dynamite, flint, quill & parchment, devilishly good looks");
String threeItems = s.nextLine();
```

At this point, I want to display the three items the user picks out without directly printing what the user wrote. I thought about doing an `if` `else` statement but the amount of items would cause that part of the code to become extremely nested, which I do not want.

```
System.out.println("That's right, you brought: " + threeItems);
```

Thank you everyone for helping me on this! stackoverflow is a great community and I am glad to be a part of it!

Comment: **1)** What you mean by: `it specifies each item, and not just a copy of what the input is into the variable 'threeItems'` **2)** If you don't want that amount of nested `if`s then you could use a `switch`

Comment: This question is so open ended. What do you want to do beyond just print back to the screen what the items are?

Comment: Are you saying something like, the user enters some text and you check what he/she has typed and match it with the list of items you have and display the item selecting it from the list??

Comment: yes darzen, sorry for being so open ended. I could not think of how to explain it. I want to be able to verify that the 3 items are items you can pick, and not just any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Map to structure your items where the key is the application-specified item name and value a simple boolean which marks an item as being in possession by your character. You would set the boolean flag when the user input is a match to an item in the map.

With this data structure you would then simply iterate through the Map and add any item names that are "in possession" to the `threeItems` output variable.

How you do the mappings is up to you. Your code currently seems to suggest that the user enter a comma-delimited list of items on a single line and then hits enter. This could work but is error prone and you would have to parse the input.

I would suggest a loop which would ask the user to enter a single item name at a time and provide a way to exit the loop.

**Follow up @Krzysztof in response to comment below**: I didn't realize you needed to keep the selected list ordered. If you were to stick with the Map then you could use ints instead of booleans where any non-zero value means the item is in possession and the value would be the order of the item. The issue with this solution is that the Map while useful in the earlier scenario now becomes a hindrance.

Now, instead of using a Map I would suggest using Lists or rather, ArrayLists. Others have suggested Lists and arrays but I'll recommend them in a more Java-esque way:

Create a `static final ArrayList<String>` and populate it with item objects (just the item names really) in a constructor or initialization block. ([ArrayList tutorial here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaDatastructureList/article.html).) Create a similar ArrayList for Items in possession which will initially be empty. Populate the list as the user enters the inventory of items. The index of the item +1 in the list is it's place in possession. Don't get cute with 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc. Use KISS: Item 1: ... Item 2: ... etc.

Comment: If I were to use a hashmap and assign each item a reference number, how would i write the code in a while loop so that it checks each value in the hashmap and if the value is contained in the hashmap it asks for the 2nd item, 3rd item, and then closes? Thank you for your answer by the way! I am still new to java (obviously) and trying to learn from internet alone!

Comment: @Krzysztof: Hmm. I didn't realize you needed to keep the selected list ordered. If you were to stick with the Map then you could use ints instead of booleans where any non-zero value means the item is in possession and the value would be the order of the item. The issue with this solution is that the Map while useful in the earlier scenario now becomes a hindrance. Updating my answer...

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible options for this that really depend on how you want to work with the data.

The items could be an [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) and then use something like an [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) to keep track of what you have in your inventory.

You could just store the items in a String array.  Or an [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of Strings (ArrayList or LinkedList), or [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of Strings (HashSet, TreeSet).

You could have each item be its own class and object.  Use [annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/) to specify which item in the inventory it is and then annotations (but this is an implementation detail).  And then you could put the verbs available on the items.

The options are really limitless and depend quite a bit on how you want to have the program work with the items and the inventory.  For this, you really do need to think through the problem and the design of the game a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the user enters the information. If they input "knife, pistol, key" you would interpret that differently than "knife pistol key."

If you would like to do it that way, look into using the `split` function. So, if you wanted to split the first way, it would go something like this:

`String[] items = threeItems.split(", ");`

where `items[0]` = "knife", the first thing they wrote, `items[1]` would equals "pistol", etc.

However, it might be better to clarify how the user should enter the input so you don't need to deal with a bunch of edge cases on how the user might format their input. You could have a new line for each item, like this:

```
System.out.print("First Item: ");
String first = s.next();
System.out.println();
System.out.print("Second Item: ");
String first = s.next();
System.out.println();
System.out.print("Third Item: ");
String first = s.next();
System.out.println();
```

The user enters an item on each line, and now you have their inputs in three seperate variables. This reduces the variability on how the user may enter information and allow for a cleaner, less-error prone game.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have not learned the split function yet, but having the user input their items one at a time makes a lot more sense then having them type all items at once!